# PostgreSQL: Return nulls as blanks for a single query

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres (Version 10) set to display nulls as '<null>'.
I know I can use COALESCE to influence the display of null columns.

What I want to know:

Is there some simpler way than multiple COALESCE statements, for a single complex query, to get the null values from outer joins returned as blank instead of '<null>'.

Thx.

Comment: What client are you using to run the query?  Are you trying to change how a null value is displayed, or trying to not have null values?  coalesce doesn't change how a null is displayed, it returns the first non-null result, if any.

Comment: If you want actual blank, as in empty, then COALESCE. Otherwise change your client display settings.

Comment: Excel and SQLWorkbench at this time. Trying to change how the nulls are displayed. I want blanks. AFAIK, Coalesce requires a value of the same type so for numerics you would get a zero. Excel is doing it OK, as it is set to display blanks.